# Why can I use `to` in the first argument of Future.traverse, but not `until`?

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

Why can I use `to` to construct a `Range` for the first argument of `Future.traverse`, but not `until`? See the following example Scala console interaction.

```
scala> Future.traverse(1 to 5)(Future.successful)
val res5: scala.concurrent.Future[IndexedSeq[Int]] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> Future.traverse(1 until 5)(Future.successful)
                                 ^
       error: Cannot construct a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.AbstractSeq[Int] with elements of type Int based on a collection of type scala.collection.immutable.AbstractSeq[Int].

scala> res5
val res7: scala.concurrent.Future[IndexedSeq[Int]] = Future(Success(Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))

scala>
```

Note that I'm using Scala 2.13.5 for the console though Scala 2.13.2 seems to have the same behavior.

For what it's worth, I noticed that `to` returns `Range.Inclusive`, and `until` returns `Range.Exclusive`. But both extend `Range`, so I'm at a loss as to what is different between these two types such that `Future.traverse` can take one but not the other as the first argument.

Comment: It seems to be related to an [open bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6948) reported years ago.  The issue appears to be gone in Scala 3.

Comment: For what it's worth, an explicit type signature will fix it. `Future.traverse[Int, Int, IndexedSeq](1 until 5)(Future.successful)` works.

Comment: Cute. Thanks! Looks like the type signature of `Range` starting with extending `AbstractSeq` rather than `IndexedSeq` actually made a difference.

Comment: @LeoC Yes, I think you're right on that one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a combination of several problems.

`1 until 5` returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Range`, while `1 to 5` returns `Range.Inclusive`.

```
scala> val exclusive: Range.Exclusive = 1 until 5
                                          ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : scala.collection.immutable.Range
        required: Range.Exclusive

scala> val inclusive: Range.Inclusive = 1 to 5
val inclusive: Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 5
```

`Range.Inclusive` is a concrete class, and `scala.collection.immutable.Range` is the parent of both `Range.Inclusive` and `Range.Exclusive`. It looks as though due to the [open bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6948) Leo C mentioned, `scala.collection.immutable.Range` considered only `AbstractSeq` rather than `IndexedSeq` (as Silvio Mayolo's comment suggested). And `AbstractSeq` cannot be constructed. `Range.Inclusive`, being a concrete class, does not have the same problem.

I am not sure at this point why `AbstractSeq` cannot be constructed. I had thought the reason was that `AbstractSeq` is `abstract`, but `IndexedSeq` is a trait as well. That said, it is probably by design that `AbstractSeq` cannot be constructed, but IndexedSeq can.